# In JSDoc, how to apply param type as bunch of strings from a constant array of objects string property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, documentation, jsdoc

Let's say I have an object like this;

```js
const typesOfIceCreams = [
 {id: "CHOCOLATE", price: 0.49, rating: 4.5},
 {id: "CHERRY", price: 0.54, rating: 4.3},
 {id: "LEMON", price: 0.44, rating: 4.6},
]
```

I want to get an object from `typesOfIceCreams` array by `id` property. So I have a function like this;

```js
/**
* @param {?} iceCreamId
*/
const getIceCreamById = (iceCreamId) => {
 return typesOfIceCreams.find(iceCream => iceCream.id === iceCreamId);
}
```

`* @params { "CHOCOLATE" | "CHERRY" | "LEMON" } iceCreamId`

I could have written like this. But it is time-consuming whenever I want to add new ice cream data to the array. I would like something similar to this;

`* @params { typesOfIceCreams.map(iceCream => iceCream.id) }`

Thus, I will be able to see that three options `("CHOCOLATE" | "CHERRY" | "LEMON")` whenever I try to call `getIceCreamById()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick. Just cast the array to `const`.

```js
const typesOfIceCreams = /** @type {const} */([
  {id: "CHOCOLATE", price: 0.49, rating: 4.5},
  {id: "CHERRY", price: 0.54, rating: 4.3},
  {id: "LEMON", price: 0.44, rating: 4.6},
])

/**
* @param {typeof typesOfIceCreams[number]['id']} iceCreamId
*/
const getIceCreamById = (iceCreamId) => {
 return typesOfIceCreams.find(iceCream => iceCream.id === iceCreamId);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]